# C#/WPF Handling active Storyboard Animations when spamming the 'Toggle'

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, storyboard

Basically I have this animation where when you click the button(s), it toggles the grid either revealing or hiding the 2nd column (which contains Button2) ... My problem is that when you spam-click the button, the animation gets queued so it needs to finish the first animation before doing the second one. The only workaround I have is to disable the button while the animation is active then re-enabling them once the animation is completed. But I'm trying to find a way where the active animation gets interrupted somehow and instead uses the current width of the grid to start the 2nd animation.

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _toggle = false;
    GridBodyWidthOne = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
    GridBodyWidthZero = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Star);
    GridBody0Width = GridBodyWidthOne;
    GridBody1Width = GridBodyWidthZero;

    storyboard = this.FindResource("expandBody0") as Storyboard;
    storyboard.FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop;
    storyboard.Completed += (object o, EventArgs ea) => {
        GridBody0.Width = GridBodyWidthOne;
        GridBody1.Width = GridBodyWidthZero;
        GridBody0.BeginAnimation(ColumnDefinition.WidthProperty, null);
        GridBody1.BeginAnimation(ColumnDefinition.WidthProperty, null);
        GridSplitter0.IsEnabled = false;};

    storyboard = this.FindResource("retractBody0") as Storyboard;
    storyboard.FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop;
    storyboard.Completed += (object o, EventArgs ea) => {
        GridBody0.Width = GridBodyWidthOne;
        GridBody1.Width = GridBodyWidthOne;
        GridBody0.BeginAnimation(ColumnDefinition.WidthProperty, null);
        GridBody1.BeginAnimation(ColumnDefinition.WidthProperty, null);
        GridSplitter0.IsEnabled = true;};
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ToggleMainBody1();
}

private void ToggleMainBody1()
{
    double maxWidth = GridBody0.ActualWidth + GridBody1.ActualWidth;
    double width0 = GridBody0.ActualWidth / maxWidth;
    double width1 = GridBody1.ActualWidth / maxWidth;
    GridBody0Width = new GridLength(width0, GridUnitType.Star);
    GridBody1Width = new GridLength(width1, GridUnitType.Star);

    if (!_toggle)
        RevealMainBody1();
    else
        HideMainBody1();

    _toggle = !_toggle;
}

private void HideMainBody1()
{
    //storyboard = this.FindResource("retractBody0") as Storyboard;
    //storyboard.Stop(this);
    storyboard = this.FindResource("expandBody0") as Storyboard;
    storyboard.Begin(this);
}

private void RevealMainBody1()
{
    //storyboard = this.FindResource("expandBody0") as Storyboard;
    //storyboard.Stop(this);
    storyboard = this.FindResource("retractBody0") as Storyboard;
    storyboard.Begin(this);
}
```

as for why I have FillBehavior set to 'Stop', I have a problem with the GridSplitter if it's set to 'HoldEnd'. 'HoldEnd' actually works well but not when I adjust it via the GridSplitter. So basically, the problem occurs when you double-click the toggle button (or trigerring the toggle twice without having the first animation finish).

```
<Window x:Class="ColumnAdjustmentV2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ColumnAdjustmentV2"
    xmlns:g="clr-namespace:ColumnAdjustmentV2"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="650" Width="800" Loaded="Window_Loaded" SizeChanged="Window_SizeChanged" StateChanged="Window_StateChanged" >
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="expandBody0">
        <!--<g:GridLengthAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0" Duration="0:0:0.5" Storyboard.TargetName="GridBody0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" From="{Binding Path=GridBody0Width}" To="{Binding Path=GridBodyWidthOne}" />-->
        <g:GridLengthAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0" Duration="0:0:0.5" Storyboard.TargetName="GridBody1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" From="{Binding Path=GridBody1Width}" To="{Binding Path=GridBodyWidthZero}" />
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="retractBody0">
        <!--<g:GridLengthAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0" Duration="0:0:0.5" Storyboard.TargetName="GridBody0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" From="{Binding Path=GridBody0Width}" To="{Binding Path=GridBodyWidthOne}" />-->
        <g:GridLengthAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0" Duration="0:0:0.5" Storyboard.TargetName="GridBody1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" From="{Binding Path=GridBody1Width}" To="{Binding Path=GridBodyWidthOne}" />
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="500" />
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="GridBody0" Width="{Binding Path=GridBody0Width, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="GridBodyDivider" Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="GridBody1" Width="{Binding Path=GridBody1Width, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Button x:Name="Button1" Grid.Column="0" Content="Button1" Click="Button_Click" />
        <GridSplitter x:Name="GridSplitter0" Grid.Column="1" Background="#FFCC0099" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" Width="4" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" LayoutUpdated="GridSplitter_LayoutUpdated" MouseDoubleClick="GridSplitter_MouseDoubleClick" PreviewKeyDown="GridSplitter_PreviewKeyDown" PreviewMouseUp="GridSplitter_PreviewMouseUp" />
        <Button x:Name="Button2" Grid.Column="2" Content="Button2" Click="Button_Click" />
    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Button x:Name="Button3" Content=""/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

[image: xaml]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2iE8cZC6EFQ

Comment: can you include your full XAML as text (and not as screenshot)?

Comment: Updated with XAML, I could also update the code behind to include everything else if need be (I just tried to trim the code down to parts that I think would matter, but I could be missing some stuff)... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have prepared a sample project that I think may be helpful for you: https://github.com/Drreamer/AnimationReverse
In this example I resize a button from min to max width using animation. To start animation or to run it in reverse direction simply click the button.

```
<Grid x:Name="rootGrid">
  <Button x:Name="button" MinWidth="40" Width="40" Content="Expand" 
          local:MainWindow.AnimationDuration="0:0:2"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="button_Click" >

     <Button.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
           <BeginStoryboard>
              <Storyboard>
                 <DoubleAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetName="button"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                            From="{Binding ActualWidth,  ElementName=button}" 
                            Duration="{Binding Path=(local:MainWindow.AnimationDuration), ElementName=button}">
                    <DoubleAnimation.To>
                       <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ToWidthConverter}">
                          <Binding  ElementName="button" Path="Tag" />
                          <Binding  ElementName="button" Path="MinWidth" />
                          <Binding  ElementName="rootGrid" Path="ActualWidth" />
                       </MultiBinding>
                    </DoubleAnimation.To>
                 </DoubleAnimation>     
              </Storyboard>
           </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
     </Button.Triggers>
  </Button>
</Grid>
```

Here I use binding to dynamically set the To and Duration properties. I store information about current animation direction in the Tag property. The Duration is calculated dynamically from the Button.Click event based on the current element width. The goal here is to make sure that animation is always aplied with the same speed.

```
    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
   double currentPosition = (button.ActualWidth - button.MinWidth) / (rootGrid.ActualWidth - button.MinWidth);
   if (button.Tag is bool && (bool)button.Tag)
      button.Tag = false;
   else {
      currentPosition = 1 - currentPosition;
      button.Tag = true;
   }
   SetAnimationDuration(button, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5 * currentPosition)));
}
```

Comment: Apparently my math just wasn't right (forgot swapping the 'to' and 'from'), but seeing your answer, I'd like to study it and add it to my arsenal as well, thanks!